# Pull data from SQL Server via SQLClient in Swift

Tags: sql, sql-server, swift, sqlclient

I am trying to pull data from SQL Server and I can't store data. I am getting all rows but "outside" the function my data is zero. It means before I disconnect from DB I have data, but when I close connection all data disappeared.

I am thinking this is because I have shallow copies and I need deep copying

```
import Foundation
import SQLClient

class RecipeViewModel{
var recipes = [Recipe]()

init(){
    getRecipeFromDB()
}

func getRecipeFromDB(){

    let client = SQLClient.sharedInstance() as! SQLClient

    client.connect("x.x.x.x", username: "xx", password: "xxx", database: "xxx") {
        success in
        client.execute("SELECT item FROM TABLE") {
            results in

            for table in results as! [[[String:AnyObject]]] {
                for row in table {

                    for (columnName, value) in row {
                        let recipe = Recipe(code: value as! String, title: "Title")
                        recipes.append(recipe)
                        }
                    }
                }
// prints all recipes. Everything is perfect

        for i in self.recipes{
            print(i.code)
        }
            client.disconnect()
        }
//prints nothing. recipe.count = 0

        for i in self.recipes{
            print(i.code)
        }
    }
}

func error(error: String!, code: Int32, severity: Int32) {
    print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: try the second for loop outside the " client.connect("x.x.x.x", username: "xx", password: "xxx", database: "xxx") " part. In other words, try putting the second for loop just before the last "}" in your getRecipeFromDB function

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you are executing the print recipes right after the closure. Since the closure in the funciton is not being run sequentially, you shouldn't read the data immediately after the function with closure (There is no guarantee that the closure will be executed before the next statement below your outside function). You must use a `completion` closure to archive your goal.

```
func getRecipeFromDB(completion: ([Recipe]) -> Void){

    let client = SQLClient.sharedInstance() as! SQLClient

    client.connect("x.x.x.x", username: "xx", password: "xxx", database: "xxx") {
        success in
        client.execute("SELECT item FROM TABLE") {
            results in

            for table in results as! [[[String:AnyObject]]] {
                for row in table {

                    for (columnName, value) in row {
                        let recipe = Recipe(code: value as! String, title: "Title")
                        recipes.append(recipe)
                    }
                }
            }
            // prints all recipes. Everything is perfect

            for i in self.recipes{
                print(i.code)
            }
            client.disconnect()

            // This is important to invoke the callback when reading data is done
            completion(self.recipes)
        }
    }
}

// Call your query data with a completion
getRecipeFromDB {
    (data) in
    for i in data{
        print(i.code)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the message. I have tried this code. It works. I can get access to the data, but I can't populate my recipe array. It is still empty.

Comment: getRecipeFromDB {
            (data) in
            for i in data{
                self.viewModel.recipes.append(Recipe(recipeCode: i.recipeCode!, recipeTitle: i.recipeTitle!))
            }
        }

Comment: you mean `data` in the `getRecipeFromDB ` function is empty?

Comment: `data` in the `getRecipeDB` is full. I am trying to populate `var recipes = [Recipe]()` in `class` to use this variable. I want to call `getRecipeFromDB` once when I initialize viewModel and use only `recipes` after. So when I call `self.recipes.append[i]` in for loop and after call `recipes` it is still empty

Comment: I have figured out. Just call `getRecipeFromDB` in `viewDidLoad` and populate `recipes`. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoPLx.png)The best way to use Obj-C in a Swift project is to use a bridging header file, what I did with SQLCLient was to drag and drop the files from SQL client and then Xcode will ask if you want to create a bridging header file, select yes.

Inside the bridging header file, import "SQLClient.h", from here you can build the project and everything should compile. You can then create a SQLClient object like you did above and inside the .connect you make the sure the completion handler checks if it was successful then inside the closure you can call client.execute and from here if you put a SQL command as a string and use data as a variable inside the .execute completion block, if you print this data variable you will return all of the data from the SQL Server. It returns in JSON, so from here you can convert using JSON Serialization.

If you have any questions, please feel free to message me and I will return a screenshot of what my code looked like so that it may help you!